# Views: showing similar terms on term page by another term reference field

Tags: 7, views

I've got 2 vocabularies, for example, artists and styles.

When viewing one of the Artists term i want to show another artists terms in a block, marked with the same term from styles vocabulary by reference field.

How to achieve it?

I tried to set the relation to Taxonomy Term: Styles (field_styles) and various contextual filters but without success.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you put the vocabularies and term refernce fields into the context of the content you would like to show? As it is it is not clear just what youa re trying to do.

Comment: I've got Artists terms and each of them has references to styles term.
I just want to show a block with similar (having the same style set) terms from vocabulary Artist when one of this Artist term is viewed.
Could you please explain more specific the contexts i should use? Thanks for a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a term reference field attached to the Artist vocabulary showing terms from the Styles vocabulary, and assuming that you wish to display a list of other Artists with the same Styles in a block ...

Create a block view showing taxonomy terms from the Artist vocabulary.

Set a Conceptual filter on `Taxonomy term: Tid` and provide a default value of *Term ID from URL*.

Add a relationship on `Taxonomy term:Styles (field_styles)` and check *Require this relationship*.

Add a second relationship to `Taxonomy term: Taxonomy term using Styles`. Configure it to use the relationship *term from field_styles* and check it as required.

Go to your view fields and edit the `Taxonomy term: Name` field. Configure it to use the *field_styles* relationship.

Go to *Advanced > Other > Query options* and select *Distinct*. This type of query can produce duplicates.

Place the block on your taxonomy pages and it will give you a list of Artists with the same Style(s) as the current Artist.