# Parent term doesn't show child term entities

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

My website has  two taxonomies school and city, are connected.
Here's city term list

```
Newyork(parent)
-Yonkers(sub-term)
-Albany(sub-term)
-New Rochelle(sub-term)
-Utica(sub-term)
```

And school term has a city_field connected (with term referenced) to city taxonomy.
 I can list schools according to city terms(eg:newyork schools)

**Problem:**
All city terms show  schools. That's ok. But parent term(newyork) doesn't show subterm(Yonker, Albany, New Rochelle,Utica) schools.

Newyork (parent term) shows schools if only newyork selected. It should show other city schools under newyork.

**What I did:**

I've tried to add parent relationship, no result. I've tried to add parent relationship to contextual field, taxonomy term:name field and criteria and many combinations. No result...

**Here's view structure:**
I've done with prkos help term to term relationship view . You may check [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267615/how-can-i-show-referenced-terms-on-other-term-page-with-view/267664?noredirect=1#comment328106_267664) if you want to see how it'shandled.

Any help or article guide with this would be awesome . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, although there may be a more elegant solution. I had to use two additional modules: [Views arg parent term](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arg_parent_term) and [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or). There are a lot of `LEFT JOIN`s so it's not very performance friendly.

The problem actually lies in listing the children terms (Yonkers, Albany, etc) of the term page you're currently viewing (Newyork), along with the term of the page itself (Newyork). Once you solve that it's simple to pull information about the terms from School term vocabulary that reference your City terms (through a Relationship).

### List the term and its children on the term page

1. Start with Taxonomy Term View type (Block Display), filter to list only City vocabulary. Add Fields for Term ID or Term name to display Cities just to test that all are there (you should see all Cities listed).

   You can add the relevant School terms (that reference the term listed) although it's not yet necessary, we can take care of it when we get the correct contextual filtering.
2. Add a Contextual filter **Term ID** from `Taxonomy term` Category, and configure it with these options:
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **Taxonomy term ID from URL**
   **Load default filter from term page**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **Taxonomy term**
   **City**
   `Filter value type`: **Term ID**

   You can now test this filter by entering a City term ID into the Preview field, it should limit the results list to show only that City views row. (You can see all of the results by entering `all` into Preview.)
3. To list child City terms add a **Relationship `Parent term`** from `Taxonomy term` Category, don't require it or it will limit the results beyond what is useful to this case
4. Add another Contextual filter **Term ID** from `Taxonomy term` Category, make it use the Parent Relationship from the previous step and configure it similarly to the last one, only change one option: filter `Type`:
   Taxonomy **parent** term ID from URL
5. Under Views `Query settings` tick **Contextual filters OR**, best to apply it only to this Block so it doesn't interfere with your other Displays if you have them.

   This will make all Contextual filters work with an `OR` operator instead of `AND`. In your case it will allow Views to filter by term ID of the page you're viewing OR it's child, so both options will be valid.

   You can now enter a city term ID twice into Preview and you'll see both that term and its children. For example, let's say your Newyork term ID is 18, if you enter `18/18` into Preview you'll see all the terms from your City vocabulary.

   ### Show which terms reference the ones listed
6. To show the School terms that reference City terms add a **Relationship Taxonomy term using City**. You can require it, this will exclude all City terms from the list that aren't referenced by any School terms. Since it's a School terms list we want in the end it doesn't make sense to allow any "empty" rows.
7. Add a **Field Taxonomy term: Name** and make it use the Relationship from the previous step (field_city).

   You can now see the relevant School terms in your results! You can now remove the City TID and Name fields, if you don't need them for the testing, so you only end up with School terms.
8. Place the Block on your City term pages and it will list School terms that reference that term or its children. You'll probably only want to place it on first level term pages (Newyork) because it doesn't work in reverse, it won't display parent terms when you're viewing child term pages, it will only list their own related ones.

   ### Add the third Taxonomy level
9. Just in case someone needs it, if the Vocabulary has the third level, to show grandchildren on parent pages you have to add another **Relationship Parent term**, make it use the earlier Parent Relationship, don't require it.
10. Add another **Term ID** Contextual filter and configure it like the second one, with `Taxonomy **parent** term ID from URL`, only make it use the second `Parent` Relationship.

    You'll now have to enter the parent TID thrice to make the Preview work `18/18/18`. (This doesn't affect the Block, arguments are handled automatically.)